Comparing two tables in sql and getting the right info using Select
Can you please give me a query in Sql?
I have tables freshdesk and storage. I need to get all the records from freshdesk and it should compare the storage table, It should get the matching records which ever are in Freshdesk matching with storage. Also if any new records are in storage, i have to retrieve those records too, and if there is any modified information in storage table when comapring with Freshdesk, it should get the updated information from storage.
Below is the query i tried.
SELECT f.* FROM freshdesk f LEFT JOIN storage s ON f.id = s.id
UNION
SELECT s.* FROM storage s LEFT JOIN freshdesk f ON f.id = s.id


It seems like you only want to see the records in freshdesk that match with storage, as well as all records in storage.
That's simply the definition of left join
SELECT * FROM storage
LEFT JOIN freshdesk ON storage.id = freshdesk.id

so I thought something like the above query would get what you need

Thank you all for your inputs. It helps me

To get all the records from freshdesk that are in storage table too
SELECT f.* FROM freshdesk f LEFT JOIN storage s ON f.id = s.id 

To retrieve any new record in storage,
SELECT s.* FROM storage s LEFT JOIN freshdesk f ON s.id = f.id where f.id IS NULL

and if there is any modified information in storage table when comapring with Freshdeskn then get the updated information from storage.
SELECT s.* FROM storage s INNER JOIN freshdesk f ON s.id = f.id where s.col1<> f.col1 or s.col2<>f.col2 .... or s.coln<>f.coln

so the query is
SELECT f.* FROM freshdesk f LEFT JOIN storage s ON f.id = s.id 
UNION 
SELECT s.* FROM storage s LEFT JOIN freshdesk f ON s.id = f.id where f.id IS NULL
UNION 
SELECT s.* FROM storage s INNER JOIN freshdesk f ON s.id = f.id where s.col1<> f.col1 or s.col2<>f.col2 .... or s.coln<>f.coln

